# Inheritance or Polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I did a programmer's test few weeks ago and did not pass. The test was those full of "gotch you!" c++ questions, that had nothing to do with what we face on a day to day coding. I wish I had printed out all of them and posted online, but too late. One I remember and I wonder if someone can clarify with certainty the best answer.

Does the code below show an example of inheritance or polymorphism? To me, is both, but I ended up answering inheritance since it only gave me on option to pick. The derived class is clearly inheriting properties from the base class, but since there is only a change in behavior of a method, it can also be a polymorphism example.

any comments?

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {}

    virtual int Foo(int a)
    {
        return a*a;
    }

};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}

    int Foo(int a)
    {
        return a*a*a;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's not an either/or example but polymorphism isn't in itself; it requires classes have a common base or interface.

Comment: Maybe they don't consider it isn't an example of polymorphism because there isn't any code that actually uses it.

Comment: There's a metric load of programmers' tests out there, ranging from awful to horrendous. It isn't clear why your particular test should be any different. Perhaps the question is simply a poor one and doesn't deserve much pondering upon?

Comment: It would be polymorphism if you had a part in the code (say, in the `main()`) that says: `Base b[2] = {Base(), Derived()};` for example, and then a use of the `Foo()` function in a for loop (just an example, remember). But the code doesn't have anything to do with it, it only shows two classes, one of which inherits from the other.

Comment: @ZachP Unfortunately, that wouldn't have any polymorphism in it, because the array holds `Base` objects.

Comment: @juanchopanza Indeed, my bad. I should have had a pointer array and allocated memory inside of it using the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's clearly showing inheritance.  It's hard to have polymorphism without inheritance though (although you can do compile-time polymorphism with templates).  I don't think *this* code is showing polymorphism - that has to involve using a derived object through a base pointer / reference.

So:

```
    Derived d;
    d.Foo(5);   // No polymorphism.
```

But

```
    std::unique_ptr<Base>() Factory(int i);
    auto pBase = Factory(1);
    auto a = pBase->Foo(5);  // *This* is polymorphism
```

Comment: Although it's most interesting to see an example of it being applied, I disagree with the last part of your answer. I believe it's possible to show an example of polymorphism with nothing more than class definitions.

Comment: You can also have compile time polymorphism with plain old function overloading.